# If the mp4 video was not found, throw the flv video

Tags: .htaccess

I own a video sharing website where users upload videos to it.

Usually videos get converted into mp4 file and they get streamed. However, many times due to server failures, the video gets converted to flv files. Flv and mp4 files get stored within the same location under the same name.

The player calls one video file from the source:

```
http://server.mysite.com/location/user/id/file.mp4
```

I want my server to throw the same link but with flv file instead of mp4 (if the mp4 file was not found), in this case if the mp4 video was not found the server would throw:

```
http://server.mysite.com/location/user/id/file.flv
```

How do I achieve this using htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Custom 404 page

How about dropping custom 404 error page that looks up whether alternative file exists and redirects there.

## mod_rewrite

Second option involves mod_rewrite (untested pseudo-code):

In your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (or wherever httpd.conf lives in your distro) enable RewriteEngine (you can do it per VHost too if you wish so):

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Also don't forget to set AllowOverrides for your directory:

```
<Directory /foo/bar>
   AllowOverrides  FileInfo
</Directory>
```

then in your .htaccess do:

```
RewriteBase /foo/bar
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   ^(.*).mp4 $1.flv [R=301]
```

Note that if you apply RewriteRules in .htaccess you **have to** setup RewriteBase otherwise you'll be seeing weird redirects. If you set it up from httpd.conf - you can still do it but it is not required.

As an option `[R=301]` could be replaced with [P], but that means that your software will think it's getting .mp4 file whereas in fact payload will be .flv file

see [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more info

Comment: This sounds slow and not efficient. I believe htaccess holds the most efficient solution, I think it is possible also.

Comment: @georgechalhoub sorry - didn't quite finished post when hit send. I've updated it.